# How to identify the form and function of the word "that"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinators

I understand that "that" can be either a relative pronoun or a subordinating conjunction, I just don't understand *when*. I know that both of these create dependent clauses, and I am pretty sure that subordinating conjunctions create adverb clauses (is this the same as the conjunction functioning as an adverb?) and that relative pronouns create noun and adjective clauses (again, is this the same as saying that the relative pronoun functions as a noun and an adjective?). I have been recently been working on doing some sentence analysis (breaking down a sentence into its constituent word forms and functions), and I have been told to bracket off the dependent clause that the relative pronoun starts in order to find its function. However, this is much more difficult to do with "that", since I don't know how to find out whether "that" is a relative pronoun or a conjunction, and I then don't know how to decide the function for the conjunction or relative pronoun of "that".

Comment: The grammatical term for the _that_ which heads non-relative clauses, like _She's thankful **that** you didn't buy it_, is Complementizer, because these clauses, which function as subject or object clauses most often, are called Complement Clauses. _That_-clauses are one of the four types of complement clauses in English; the others are embedded questions, like _I wonder where she went_, infinitives like _She wants to leave soon_, and gerunds like _She hates washing the sheets_. Each is marked by its own complementizer.

Comment: Can you expand on this (either in your own words or a link if it's too long to fit into a comment)? I'm new to the grammatical side of English, so I thought that the only clauses were independent and dependent? I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: Every sentence has at least one independent clause. But most independent clauses have many dependent clauses, so "complex" sentences, as they call them in elementary school, are by far the most common. As for dependent clauses, there are many, many types, and every language has its own set of clauses and rules for how they work. It's very complex and continues far beyond what you were  apparently taught in school.

Comment: If you're seriously interested in how English grammar works, I can recommend McCawley 1998. It's not simple, but it's clear. Here's a [summary handout from the syntax part of my Introduction to Linguistic Analysis](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/SyntaxTopics.pdf) class. And here are the coursepacks used as textbooks and workbooks for that class: [Part 1](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart1.pdf) covers morphology, phonetics, and phonology, while [Part 2](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart2.pdf) covers syntax, semantics, pragmatics, and selected short subjects.

Comment: You're starting off on the wrong foot. Despite what most dictionaries and some older grammars tell us, "that" is never a relative pronoun. Whether it is introducing a relative clause or a declarative content clause, it's a subordinator. The simplest way to distinguish the two kinds is to determine whether the clause has an element -- actually present or understood -- that is anaphoric to a preceding noun. If it has, then it's a relative clause; otherwise it's a declarative content clause. "I know the boy [that __ is late]" (relative clause) ~ "I know [that the boy is late]." (content clause).

Comment: Despite what anyone tells us, _that_ can be called a relative pronoun if the grammarian wishes to call it that. There is no absolute certainty about what category some chunk of language **IS** or **ISN"T**; there are only data and analyses. Categories and names come later, and are not imposed by fiat. Like any science, there is always considerable discussion and even dissent among grammarians. Anybody that lays down the law had better have more than one reference, and more than one argument. Many English speakers use _that_ as a relative pronoun, and in their grammars that's what it is.

Answer (score 1):

To presume that relative pronouns function as nouns and adjectives is faulty logic. They merely refer back to the *antecedent*, and the clauses they head are what really function as adjective clauses. And since conjunctions are merely connecting words, *that* as conjunction never refers back to *antecedent* as does the relative pronoun *that.* Once you go by this logic I'm sure you could tell one from the other lickety-split.

Thus,

> This is the book **that** Bill wrote. (Relative pronoun)

But

> It's unlikely **that** he will succeed. (Conjunction)

Comment: So no antecedent = conjunction and antecedent = relative pronoun? I think I get this now. But what is the function of that as a conjunction vs. that as a relative pronoun?

Comment: Conjunctions only connect. They do no other job. [Relative] Pronouns are used in place of nouns. Thus, they can connect as well as refer back to some antecedent. But please note that _relative adverbs_ can also connect as well as refer back to antecedents. However, they are not the same as _relative pronouns._

Comment: But a conjunction must serve some function right? Pronouns can function as subjects, indirect objects, etc. What I'm getting at is that everything must have a function, so do conjunctions just function as... conjunctions? And isn't a relative adverb just a subordinating conjunction, and I'm sure that those don't have antecedents. I'm kind of confused here.

Comment: @TheeGrammarStallion In both constructions "that" is a **subordinator**, whose function is that of **marker**. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a little trick to identify the role of "that" in any given sentence: replace it with "which" to understand whether the word serves as a conjunction or a relative pronoun.

> Example 1: They said ***that*** four million workers stayed at home to
> protest against the tax.

Replacement with "which" does not make much sense in this case, so "that" is not used here as a relative pronoun but as a conjunction. *That clauses* are usually used in combination with verb -- ***said that***, in this example -- or a noun or adjective. You can read more about this [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses).

> Example 2: He went to the school ***that*** my father went to.

Replacement with "which" fits, so in this example "that" is a relative pronoun. More on relative pronouns [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns).

Comment: That works for restrictive relative clauses, where _which_ (or _who_) can be used as a relative pronoun, and so can _that_. But it won't distinguish between complementizer _that_ (_I know that she's waiting for me_) and demonstrative _that_ (_I know that woman's waiting for me_), since neither one can substitute a _Wh_-word.

Comment: The solution differentiates a pronoun from a conjunction — the key confusion point for the OP.